# Access participant audio in a UCMA call and replace them

Tags: c#, sdp, ucma

Using UCMA 5.0 and C#, if there is a conference call between two participants, participants A and B, I would like to modify Audio that participant B hears when A speaks, and vice versa.

From my knowledge there is only AudioVideoFlow that has the combined audio of two participants, it means I could not find a way to have a distinguished audio stream of the participants, modify them and replace it in the call.

I also know the SDP protocol is responsible for medias in the call, but can not figure out how to access it or change it based on  my scenario.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [How to ask Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Abhishek As I have mentioned in the question "I could not find a way to have a distinguished audio stream", therefore there is nothing that I can use as a tried solution, since the expected method I am looking for does not exist.